# Latest Ubuntu Desktop without Unity

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

What is the latest version of Ubuntu Desktop that doesn't have Unity?

I really dislike the lack of menus. It's very hard to discover and find applications. For example, I'm looking for the activity monitor type application but I don't know the exact name. The old way of doing this is to look under System. With Unity I have to know the exact name of the application.

Comment: In fairness, I should note that the version of Unity in Ubuntu 12.04 has a richer interface for finding Apps whose names you don't know than the traditional way. You can filter by the same categories, as well as filtering by rating. Furthermore, if you want to search, that option is there as well. The current version of Unity is far better then the early releases. In summary, the current Unity is actually *better* for the purposes you described than the classic menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last versions that came without Unity were 10.10 (Desktop) and 10.04 (Netbook), but that information is rather irrelevant.

If you wish, you can install GNOME on any version of Ubuntu.

In 11.10 and later, you can install GNOME Shell from the Software Center or by executing

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

in a terminal.

Now, you can choose between GNOME and Unity by clicking the gear/Ubuntu icon on the logon screen.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Ubuntu uses Unity.  You can use the latest version of Ubuntu without Unity.  Here are some [directions](http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) on how to install Gnome 3.  However, you can use just about any window manager out there.

Personally, I like [Mint](http://linuxmint.com/) over Ubuntu.  It is Ubuntu based, but uses the Cinnamon window manager.

Comment: Does Mint have menus? I went to the Mint website but there are no screenshots.

Comment: yes it does.  I hate Unity, so I switched to Mint

Answer (score 1):

The last desktop Ubuntu that did not feature Unity would be: ([Source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_12.04#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29))

> **Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)**
>
> The naming of Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) was announced by Mark Shuttleworth on 2 April 2010, along with the release's goals of improving the netbook experience and a server focus on hybrid cloud computing. Ubuntu 10.10 was released on 10 October 2010 (10.10.10) at around 10:10 UTC.[101][102][103][104][105] This is a departure from the traditional schedule of releasing at the end of October to get "the perfect 10",[106] and a playful reference to The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, since, in binary, 101010 is equal to the number 42, the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe and Everything" within the series.[107] It was Canonical's 13th release of Ubuntu. New features included the new Unity interface for the Netbook Edition, a new default photo manager, Shotwell, replacing F-Spot, the ability to purchase applications in the Software Center, and an official Ubuntu font used by default.[108] Support of Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat 10.10 was officially dropped on 10 April 2012.[109]
>
> [image: Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) screen shot]

Comment: That one was the best

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

- or use [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com/) (the distribution preferred by the majority of linux users by [Distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/))
- or choose another ubuntu flavor by https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours